# counting letters with Recursion

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that will count the number of characters in a a string that occur in-between two identical substrings,
for example:

`strDist("cccatcowcatxx", "cat") →` should `return 9` because the number of letters in-between the two instances of cat including the the instances themselves is `9`.

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
    if (str.length() >= sub.length()){//accomodate for the last length of string hat can be equal to sub
      if ((str.substring(0,sub.length())).equals(sub)){
        return sub.length() + strDist(str.substring(sub.length(), str.length()), sub); 
      }
      else if ((str.substring(str.length() - 1, str.length()).equals(sub.substring(sub.length() - 1,sub.length())))){
        return sub.length();//return diff here
      }
      else {
          return (strDist(str.substring(1,str.length()), sub)); 
      }
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

the correct way:

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
    if (str.length() >= sub.length()){
      if ((str.substring(0,sub.length())).equals(sub)){
          if ((str.substring(str.length() - sub.length())).equals(sub)){
              return str.length();
          }
          else{
              return strDist(str.substring(0, str.length()-1), sub);
          }
      }
      else {
          return (strDist(str.substring(1), sub)); 
      }
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You might want to ask a question.

Comment: What's wrong with `return str.split(sub)[1].length() + sub.length() * 2;`?

Comment: I have to agree with @shmosel here - can you edit to include an actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming — correct me if I’m wrong — that if `sub` does not occur, result should be 0; if it occurs once, the result should be the length of `sub`; if it occurs many times, the result may be the length of the longest substring that begins and ends with `sub`.

So your outer `if` statement is sound: only if the string is long enough, go search for `sub`. Next you check if the string begins with `sub`, also a good idea. But don’t chop off `sub` from the beginning. Because if you chop off `cat` from `catcowcat`, the recursive call `strDist("cowcat", "cat")` will not return 6 (at least it should not). Instead I suggest, see if the string also ends with `sub`. If it does, just return the length of the entire string. If it doesn’t, chop one char off the *end* and call recursively.

A couple of tips: Instead of `str.substring(0,sub.length()).equals(sub)` you may do just `str.startsWith(sub)`. Instead of `str.substring(1,str.length())` you may write just `str.substring(1)` if you like, this does the same.

EDIT: Glad you got it to work, classic_man. I am formatting your fixed/working code from the comment and pasting it in here in case anyone else wants to read it:

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
    if (str.length() >= sub.length()) {
        if ((str.substring(0, sub.length())).equals(sub)) {
            if ((str.substring(str.length() - sub.length())).equals(sub)) {
                return str.length();
            } else {
                return strDist(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1), sub);
            }
        } else {
            return (strDist(str.substring(1), sub));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ole V.V. after following your advice i got it to work.

Comment: public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
  if (str.length() >= sub.length()){
    if ((str.substring(0,sub.length())).equals(sub)){
     if ((str.substring(str.length() - sub.length())).equals(sub)){
      return str.length();
     }
     else{
      return strDist(str.substring(0, str.length()-1), sub);
     }
    }
    else {
     return (strDist(str.substring(1), sub)); 
    }
  }
  return 0; 
 }